# Custom splash screen with animation-Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, splash-screen, fade

I am trying to show a splash screen with an animation, and I found this article: https://medium.com/@galadhruvil7/flutter-splash-screen-animation-16c50e18b9d8 I think that's very simple but wonderful, the case is I would like to change the flutter icon into another image and text. Here is the code

```
SplashScreenState() {
    _timer = new Timer(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      setState(() {
        assetImage = Row(
          children: [
            Image.asset('assets/logo.png', height: 500, width: 500),
            Text("trial")
          ],
        );
      });
    });
  }
```

and showing the widget like this:

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: assetImage,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

but by running that code, there is no animation effect. Is there a way to keep the animation like the source that I have given while the Flutter logo is changed into image and text ?

Comment: no there isnt. you can copy the code (CTRL+tap) and use your own image and text but flutter doesn't have customisation for that widget.

Answer (score 0):

Through `AnimatedSwitcher` with conditional operators you can change your logo with icon and text.

Example - [AnimatedSwitcherExample](https://medium.com/flutter-community/what-do-you-know-about-aniamtedswitcher-53cc3a4bebb8)